# Select items in a listbox from database

Tags: asp.net, sql, winforms, listbox

I have a database with 2 tables. One table lists employees (EmployeeID, First, Last, ect.), the other training per employee (EmployeeID, TrainingID, etc.) The employeeID is common between the two tables. I currently have a listbox on a windows form that is databound to the employees table. The end user selects the employees on the list box and then saves the employees to the training table.

What I would like to do is select the employees who have already had the training in the employees listbox. In other words, if there are 50 employees, and one location does a training and returns a list of 10 names, those names are stored in the training table. When the next set of training is turned in (say 5 employees), the 10 that had previously been entered are already selected in the listbox (Or the names are bolded, italicized, or otherwise stand out against the listbox). I know that I will have to then do a check on the save to make sure I'm not writing a duplicate value, I just want to be able to mark the employees who are current in their training.

I found a question on here with an answer in C#, but I was unable to get it to work in VB.NET. Just so we're clear, the listbox is databound using one table, and the items are selected using a second table.

**Edit:** I have a tableadapter that pulls a list of employees that have already been entered into the database called `DFV_EmployeesByWeeklyTraining`. The Rows are returned by the following `SELECT WeeklyTrainingID, TopicDescription, EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.DFV_EmployeesByWeeklyTraining(@WeeklyTrainingID)`. This is the information I need to search.

My listbox pulls data from `DFV_EmployeesByDate` which returns the EmployeeID and Fullname. I have set the DisplayMember as FullName and the EmployeeID as the ValueMember. I can loop through each listbox item and pull the EmployeeID, now I need to check that EmployeeID against the other tableadapter.

Comment: Curious what was the code in c# that didn't work in VB.net?

Comment: 1: Make a list of employee ID's from the second table where Already Trained is true. 2: Loop through the listbox and select each one that can be found in the list made in step 1. At what point are you getting stuck?

Comment: @MatthewLauser -The code that checks a value against a data table.

I had found:
    if (dtPersonsCars.Rows.Find(new object[]
    {"PERSON",lstBoxAenderungen.Items[i].ToString()}) != null)
    lstBoxCars.SetSelected(i, true);

On a C# answer, but rows.find doesn't appear to work in VS 2010 on a VB.net Winforms application.

Basically, at this point I can get the value from each line in the listbox, but don't know how to check to see if that value is in a separate datatable.

Comment: Apparently, I can't master the inline code blocks either because after 10 tries of inserting spaces at the beginning of a line, or using the back ticks option I still can't get the code to show up right.

Comment: I found this example for finding a row by a column value: `Dim foundRows() As Data.DataRow`, `foundRows = DataSet1.Tables("Customers").Select("CompanyName Like 'A%'")` Here's the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.90).Aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 It appears that the "find" function is used to find a row by its primary key, while the "select" function finds a row based on a specified column value.

Comment: A workaround, if you can't get that to work, would be to make a `List<int>` of employee IDs from the DataTable (by looping through the rows and grabbing the ones where Already Trained = true), and then you can just check if the list contains a specified ID.

Comment: @MatthewLauser, your comment was very helpful. I have been using a tableadapter to pull data from a SQL function. `Me.DFV_EmployeesByWeeklyTrainingTableAdapter.GetData(TrainingID)` I do not know how to convert the tableadapter to a dataset. I managed to add some of the code from the MSDN page `foundRows = DataSet1.Tables("WeeklyTrainingEmployeeList").Select("EmployeeID = 33")` but I cannot seem to do anything with it.

Comment: I have it working in a very kludgy way, I added an invisible listbox2 and check each item in listbox1 to each item in listbox2 and select those items.